# MySQL select selected columns plus all other columns on command line

Tags: mysql

It used to be that I could fire a query like the following in a query window/sql command line, against MS SQL server:

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, * from bar
```

Basically show the specified columns followed by rest of the columns. But MySQL does not allow this; throws back a syntax error at me. Is there an alternative syntax to do this in MySQL? Note that I am NOT trying to do this in code (where it has no practical use); I am using it for firing random queries against my DB to look up information.

Comment: 'foo1, foo2, *' Doesn't make sense since '*' includes foo1 foo2.

Comment: `SELECT foo1, foo2,b.* from bar b;`

Comment: It does make sense. it doesn't **add** any information, but it does give you the thing you are looking for in the first row. See the last sentence. I use this quite often when doing a quick lookup in the database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare the table on the SELECT CLAUSE.

```
SELECT foo1, foo2, bar.* from bar;
```

OR

```
SELECT b.foo1, b.foo2, b.* from bar b;
```

;-)

Comment: Thanks. That works. Simple thing; couldn't get it in manual or through a web search.

Answer (score 1):

If you name the table (either by using the full name, or by using an alias like below), you can actually get it to work (tested for version 5.5.31)

```
SELECT b.foo1, b.foo2, b.* FROM bar b
```

Comment: Thanks; that works. Medina's answer below points to another way though which does not involve naming tables at all.

Comment: It is basically the same way: you reference the specific table. You can do this with the complete tablename, or with an alias like above. I have learned to always use an alias, because long tablenames will make your query unreadable otherwise, and as soon as you have a more complicated query (examples are joining twice on the same table, joining on a `SELECT` etc) you'd need an alias anyway. But in the end, they are the same thing